# Android Studio - failed to start adb

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently started learning android programming using android studio but every time I open the emulator and drag an apk to the emulator it says:

> failed to start adb - Check settings to verify your chosen adb path is
>   valid

as shown in the link below.

How can I fix this?

PS: Sorry for my English.

[image: android failed to start adb image]

Comment: Apparently, [you are not the only one getting this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225294). In the sidebar hanging off the right of the main emulator window, click the "..." at the bottom, to fold open the "extended controls". In there, click on Settings. There should be a "Use detected ADB location" switch in the right column. Is that switched on? If not, try that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did that and still have the same error. Do I need to restart android studio to apply those changes ?

Comment: Does your ADB run apps from debug?

Comment: I do not know, as I have never had to change it.

Comment: @pizzaslice I don't know, how do I check that ?

Comment: in Android Studio, where you are presumably writing this application, you should be able to hit the little "play" button at the top of the window to launch your latest build in an ADB of your choice. Click the Play button and then choose this currently running ADB.

Comment: @pizzaslice so you're telling me that the problem might be on the device configuration ?

Comment: Open up android studio and go to Tools>Android>and check Enable ADB integration.. also, are you on the latest and greatest version of android studio? or an older version...

Comment: You can also go to Tools>Android>Android Device Monitor and this should see your emulator and also be able to debug..

Comment: Changing the adb path would be ill-advised in this case, since it will not solve the issue and can lead to undesired results for normal testing. The screenshot indicates the posted answer is correct.

Answer (score 48):

Step1 : Goto your Emulator settings
[image: Settings screenshot]

Step2 : General -> "Use detected ADB location" option , disable this option and select folder path for adb.exe which is ideally (windows) is c:\users"loginuser"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

This option worked for me !!

Comment: This solved my problem. Wish I were the OP. I would definitely accept this as an answer!

Comment: You are my hero. The best answer!

Comment: Easy answer!!!!

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error, and for me, it occured because I was trying to install an APK built for ARMv7 on the emulator, which requires an x86 build.
Does your build process create separate builds as well? If so, just check if you're installing the APK meant for the correct architecture!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The screenshot shows the APK installer popup from attempting to drag and drop an APK onto the emulator to install. You could create an ARMv7 AVD or use an x86 APK. Either will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened with me, I was trying to install my apk on X86 emulator. I found two issues -

1. My apk was not completely downloaded and I was trying it to install.
2. When I resolved my first issue, I tried with terminal/command prompt and found my emulator doesn't have sufficient storage left.

**Screenshot of error** -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just wipe your android emulator data and you should be fine, worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Just close Emulator/AVD Device
Launcher again from Android Studio it will work