# The screenshot could not be captured Check settings to verify that your chosen adb path is valid

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio for my Android native project. I have updated Android Studio to newest. Use detected ADB location is enable. But when i click on screen shot button on the right bar, the error appear.

[image]

Before update I can take the screenshot when press button take screenshot. But now, i get it error. How can i fix it? Thank for any idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - failed to start adb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337336/android-studio-failed-to-start-adb)

Comment: Try to enable/disable adb from studio menu: `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration`

Comment: unlucky, it not work for me

Comment: I just recreated the AVD -changed system image- and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 week, I go to About->check for update and update Android Studio again, this error not happen any more.

```
Android Studio 2.3.1
Build #AI-162.3871768, built on April 1, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_92-b14 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```