# Using the Android Emulator M1 Mac Test, how could I fix this ADB issue?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to install an APK on the M1 Mac Android Emulator Test.

However, when I try to do it, it gives me a `"Failed to start ADB. Check settings to verify your chosen ADB path is valid."` error. I have unchecked and checked the option to auto-detect ADB but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337336/android-studio-failed-to-start-adb

Comment: I checked this post first. Answers didn't help me.

Comment: why dont you manually add the adb path refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x

Comment: adb is android debug bridge and its installed in android studio platform tools

Comment: just check the first answer there are many ways