# Android Studio Emulator won't open apk - error message "fail to start ADB"

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to drag and drop an Apk file into android studio emulator and this error message popped up -
"failed to start adb. Check settings to verify your chosen ADB path is valid."
[failed to start adb error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfUJg.jpg)

I've tried copying the apk and android studio, but the run button is greyed out. wondering if the problem is with the apk, though I have tried multiple apks.
[greyed out run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQzAw.png)

I'm on mac 11 and have no coding experience/experience with android studio. Please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337336/android-studio-failed-to-start-adb

Comment: I've seen this one. I don't know which folder to redirect ADB to, though.